# Multilingual application images

Tags: android

In my app I want show some image if the language is English and another image when the language is something else. I did it with the strings in string.xml by providing values-ru and other values folders. But I don't know how to change image like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it in exactly the same way as you did with strings.

Create a folder called **drawable-ru** in your res folder and this folder will be used for your drawables if the user is using Russian language.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it for example drawable-ru-xhdpi etc like you did it with the values folders